# scheduled agent is not started on Domino server

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

On Domino 9.x we have two databases. Both signed by same ID. Scheduled agents (-Any Server-) in db #1 start and work perfect. Scheduled agents in db #2 don't start. There is nothing in log.nsf. No output from LotuScirpt and Java agents. Databases ACL and properties are identical. So, is there something I need to enable on Domino itself (add db #2 to some list to start scheduled agents)?

Comment: Disable Background Agents set in one of the databases? (first Tab of database properties) or it has .ntf extension...

Comment: Have you used the 'Tell AMGR schedule' command to generate a listing of the agent manager's scheduling info?  Or 'Tell AMGR debug' with any of the arguments listed here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSKTMJ_8.5.3/com.ibm.help.domino.admin85.doc/H_AGENT_MANAGER_TELL_COMMANDS_8737_ABOUT.html?

Comment: "Disable Background Agent.." option unchecked on both databases. Tell AMGR schedule tells that agents are scheduled (from both databases). When I do right-click on agent in Designer then 'View Log' it says - The agent has never been run before. But agents are scheduled to run every 1 hour

Comment: I would enable the 'tell AMGR debug' command with the v argument for verbose output and leave it on for a couple of hours to see if anything interesting appears in the log. (The technote for debug_AMGR in notes.ini says it goes to log.nsf, so I assume the tell command does the same. It's been too long since I've had cases like this, so I can't rely on my memory.)

Comment: Thank you all. .tell AMGR debug helped.. Found some issues with user rights and external java API libraries